Fan switch power
The entire switch assembly is removed from the fixture. No connection to any power source. Why did I get shocked and then was able to produce spark with a screwdriver at plug in point, still connected to nothing?

Did the power go though the switch first or the fixture?  You never trust a switch to be not shocked to death.  You use the breaker always.

Everything is disconnected. The switch assembly is separated from the entire housing and the lights or ANY power source. At the connector with 7 prongs is where I was shocked.

I replaced the light switch pull chain. When I turned on the power everything worked but there was a pop. I turned off the switch at the wall and the pull chains and the fan keeps turning at very low speed

Because you didn't turn off the freaking breaker, and probably should not be doing wiring with your present lack of understanding of electricity. Read some books, or hire an electrician. We know for a fact that one of your statements is false, because if the thing was separated from any power source, there would be no shock, no sparks. So you don't know what you are doing...and you may yet die drying to figure it out if you go about it unsafely.

Breaker was and is off. If one of the little boxes in the fan control area are like a battery or whatever IDK main thing is the power was off and is again but when I touched the connection housing I got a shock . Like an electric fence. Sheesh. The last person to work on this gan was an  electrician and put a do not pull on the light chain. That's profesional

Here is my email. I'll send a picture of the thing disconnected... stuartclaus@yahoo.com

If the breaker is off, then something is messed up.  Some circuits are MWBC circuits and need two breakers off to be safe.  One reason to double check there is no power on the circuit, after turning the breaker off.  Turning off the wrong breaker is another reason.

Upload pictures here. Click "Edit" and then look for the "Mountain and sun" icon.

Reading your question and comments I think the term you are looking for is "stored energy". If your fan is completely disconnected from an energy source, not just the switch assembly and I mean hot neutral and ground. Then the fan itself could have some sort of capacitor or other energy source within it. It wouldn't need much just enough to excite the windings in the fan. If the fan can turn it could become a generator/alternator and create its own power. Other than that, the only thing you have left is static charge.
If you reply that the fan is completely disconnected from the power source, and there is no static or stored energy, then you need to get to a research lab immediately, because there are people willing to pay millions for a self generating power source.
Hope this helps, stay safe.
